# Broadcast receivers for Android O (SDK>25)

Tags: android

I have an app with a home widget. I use `PendingIntent` for clicked buttons on it, like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("MY_STRING_ACTION");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_btn, pendingIntent);
```

And I receive this intent action in a `BroadcastReceiver` where I manage it. This **works perfectly ONLY till Android 7.1**. Due to [Android 8 changes about `BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html) I don't know how to correctly register this broadcast receiver (can't context register it because if activity is destroyed, is's automatically unregistred).

Right now my received is declared in manifest like so:

```
     <receiver android:name="view.widget.WidgetActionsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MY_STRING_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Change the `Intent` to an explicit `Intent`, which you really should've been doing all along: `Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, WidgetActionsReceiver.class); intent.setAction("MY_STRING_ACTION");`. If you don't need the action to distinguish anything, you can then it. In either case, the `<intent-filter>` is then unnecessary.

Comment: @MikeM. oh yeah, that's right, they even mentioned in docs about explicit intents ;)

Comment: Yep. Btw, that should say "If you don't need the action to distinguish anything, you can _omit_ it." Darn autocorrect.